# Trouble getting an asset bundle registered

Tags: craft3

I have searched for a couple hours for help on this. No luck.

Following the docs [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/asset-bundles.html).

My first two passes were unsuccessful so I deleted everything and started over.

1) I created a plugin scaffolding with a single controller and successfully registered that plugin. I did not edit anything in that plugin.

2) I created the file "FooBundle.php" in the following folder structure:

```
recoveryfinder
--myPlugin
  --src
    --FooBundle.php
```

3) I edited the contents of FooBundle.php to be exactly the docs:

```
<?php
namespace ns\prefix;

use craft\web\AssetBundle;
use craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset;

class MyPluginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public function init()
    {
        // define the path that your publishable resources live
        $this->sourcePath = '@ns/prefix/resources';

        // define the dependencies
        $this->depends = [
            CpAsset::class,
        ];

        // define the relative path to CSS/JS files that should be registered with the page
        // when this asset bundle is registered
        $this->js = [
            'script.js',
        ];

        $this->css = [
            'styles.css',
        ];

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Lastly I added the following line after my {% extends "base.html" %} in my index.html. My first two lines of index.html look like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% do view.registerAssetBundle("ns\\prefix\\FooBundle") %}
```

When I refresh my site index page I get:

> ReflectionException
>
> Class ns\prefix\FooBundle does not exist

Comment: How about making it `class FooBundle extends AssetBundle`

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `FooBundle` has the classname `MyPluginAsset`rename your class to `FooBundle` and it should work (if your namespace is correct, since your information are not really detailed as always)

The docs are not supposed to be a place for copy paste but a source for information.

Comment: OK. So it is a namespace/classname error. Thanks for the pointer in the right direction. Namespaces are new to me. My last PHP work was in 4.x.

Comment: "The docs are not supposed to be a place for copy paste but a source for information.". Yep, I understand. I am still learning/rebuilding my knowledge after being out of PHP a long time. I'm really sorry for my lack of knowledge. I appreciate your patience and willingness to share and help.

Comment: It's not your fault. Craft docs are not that good. Some things are well explained there (that's why I always refer to those) and many questions here can be solved by looking in the documentation but for most things it's better/easier to look at yii2 instead of Craft

Comment: I had the same problem, but I corrected the namespace, the name of the file I had changed already. But I am still facing the same error. :(